# Python does not find packages installed without Anaconda

Tags: apt, python, python3, anaconda, kivy

I'm trying to install kivy for python 3 using apt-get:

```
    sudo apt-get install python3-kivy
```

And it is installed in

```
    /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

But, when I tried to load it in python, I get a ModuleNotFoundError

```
    Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 13 2017, 12:02:49) 
    [GCC 7.2.0] on linux
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import kivy
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'
```

When I check the system path from python, I only get packages in Anaconda:

```
    >>> import sys
    >>> print('\n'.join(sys.path))

    /home/santiago/anaconda3/lib/python36.zip
    /home/santiago/anaconda3/lib/python3.6
    /home/santiago/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
    /home/santiago/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
    /home/santiago/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision-0.2.0-py3.6.egg
```

Is there any way to include the '/usr/lib/python3' path to Anaconda?

Thanks.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1987/ (sorry, couldn't resist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anaconda isolate your python environment from the rest of the system. Thus, you only can use python packages installed with `conda` or anaconda `pip` version.

```
conda install -c conda-forge kivy
```